# Show PDF with all operators

Tags: pdf

Does any one know of a good freeware PDF inspector tool which runs on OSX (snow leopard).

I need to have the PDF displayed in plain text including it's operators. So the tool should decode all Objects (flate encoded) from an PDF into plain text including it's operators.

The reason for this is: I'm trying to extract all the text from within a PDF inside an iPhone App. I'm able to do this just fine. But I don't know which operators are use in the PDF. This results in a extracted string without any spaces and I need to know which operators are used in the document so I can figure out which operator should represent a space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with [PDF Vole](http://java.net/projects/pdfvole). It's open source (built on top of iText) and it is based on Java so it should work on OS X.

Comment: Thanks a lot... I've searched the web for 2 day's, came across numerous tools written in Python, C, Java. With GUI's or CLI interface (even tried it myself using PHP). None of them as simple as this!

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative tool for you may be Jay Berkenbilt's [**QPDF**](http://qpdf.sf.net/) (which is Open Source software, available on all major OS platforms).

Quote: *"QPDF is a command-line program that does structural, content-preserving transformations on PDF files."*

To expand all streams in `input.pdf`, run this command and open `output.pdf` in a text editor:

```
qpdf --qdf input.pdf output.pdf
```

[image: Beginning of QPDF Help Screen]